# How to parse a Hashmap in java 1.4

Tags: java, casting, hashmap

Hi i'm working with  java 1.4 and iwant to implement this :

```
// protected HashMap            droppedFileTarget;
JExpression[] params = new JExpression[2];

for (String extension   : droppedFileTarget.keySet()) {
  String  field = droppedFileTarget.get(extension);  

  params[1]=VKUtils.toExpression(ref, extension);
  params[2]=VKUtils.toExpression(ref, field);
}
```

but i'm getting this compilation error :

```
type mismatch : can not convert from Object to String
```

Even after type cast but the error persists :

```
   for (String extension   : (String) droppedFileTarget.keySet())
```

Comment: Hold on: This code won't compile in Java 1.4, since you're using the enhanced `for` loop. If you're using modern Java, go ahead and use Generics; they're designed specifically to avoid this error. (Additionally, use `entrySet()` instead of calling `get()` all the time.)

Comment: Java 1.4 is "End of public updates" five years ago next month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example, you're trying to cast the entire keyset to a String, which is wrong for several reasons. If you insist on not using generics, then instead, get each element as an `Object`, and *then* cast it to a `String`.

```
Iterator i = droppedFileTarget.entrySet().iterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry entry = i.next();
  String extension = (String)entry.getValue();
  String  field = droppedFileTarget.get(extension);  

  params[1]=VKUtils.toExpression(ref, extension);
  params[2]=VKUtils.toExpression(ref, field);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the keySet to `Set<String>`.

Comment: Generics is not quite workable solution in java 1.4 (assuming the OP actually *needs* to use 1.4).

Comment: True, but he's also using the for-each loop, so his source is at least 1.5. Don't know how that would affect the code. It could compile the way I wrote it.